# css button browser issue (background image)

Tags: html, css, background

I'm having a little issue here. Whatever i do, chrome and firefox seems to render this css code different. The button (Logg inn) in chrome, seems to be a little bit off, but if i use a margin-top (with negative numbers) both browsers will push the button towards the top section of the page.

[image: firefox on top, chrome on the bottom]

CSS Code

```
    #top_wrapper #login_form #btn_login {
        width: 75px;
        height: 30px;
        background-image: url('../img/btn/login.png');
        border: none;
    }
```

Do i need to target Chrome only? or what can i do, and how do i fix this? any help would be great!

HTML Code

```
<div id="login_form">

    <form id="form_login" action="" method="POST">

        <input class="form_login" type="text" value="Brukernavn" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Brukernavn')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value == '')this.value='Brukernavn'" />
        <input class="form_login" type="password" value="Passord" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Passord')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value == '')this.value='Passord'" />
        <input id="btn_login" title="Logg inn" type="submit" value="" />

    </form>

    <div id="lost_password_btn">
        <img title="Mistet passordet?" src="img/btn/lost_password.png" />
    </div> <!-- end lost_password_btn -->

</div> <!-- end login_form -->
```

Comment: Just a guess out of the blue. But you don't use a png for the background-image that has a transparent area left on the top part?

Comment: Where's the top_wrapper div? (I don't see it defined in your HTML)

Comment: The HTML (Top_Wrapper) is there, but it's just too much HTML, and it has nothing to do with the form button.

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 in Chrome and use the development tools to determine where the space is coming from.

Comment: i've already done this, with no luck. The button goes outside the "form area"

Comment: The development tools didn't show a margin or padding and gave no clue to the unintentional space? I find that hard to believe.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem by floating the form input elements, dunno why i didn't do this before. Thanks anyway.